# InnoDB engine getting disabled after decreasing innodb_page_size to 4K

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I'm trying to optimize my database (mariadb) for high write (insert & update).

Database is running fine with default  `innodb_page_size` (16K), but when I decrease the value of `innodb_page_size=4K`.

Database server starts successfully, but getting error while creating table on `InnoDB` engine.

`Error Code: 1286. Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'`

Here is my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-3.kannel.com.err
performance-schema=0

max_allowed_packet=268435456

event_scheduler = ON
#innodb_page_size=16384
#innodb_page_size=8192
innodb_page_size=4K
innodb_file_per_table=4
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=2
innodb_log_file_size=1024M
innodb_log_files_in_group=4
innodb_log_buffer_size=64M
innodb_log_write_ahead_size=64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit =2
innodb_read_io_threads=32
innodb_write_io_threads=128
innodb_io_capacity=10000
innodb_thread_concurrency=2
innodb_flush_method=o_direct


join_buffer_size=512M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_rnd_buffer_size=200M
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
max_allowed_packet=26843545600
#open_files_limit=10000
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
#default-storage-engine=InnoDB
max_connections = 500
```

Thanks!

Comment: This url may convince you to leave the page size at default.  https://blog.jcole.us/2014/05/14/innodb-with-reduced-page-sizes-wastes-up-to-6-of-disk-space/

Comment: And this URL may give you hope for success with your wish to use 4k page size.  https://blog.jcole.us/2014/05/14/innodb-with-reduced-page-sizes-wastes-up-to-6-of-disk-space/

Comment: It looks like you previously tried 8K; did that work?  (Meanwhile, I am not a fan of changing this setting, and you might be the first of thousands of users to mention trying it.

Comment: (FYI, bug 67963 mentioned in Jeremy's blog was fixed in 8.0.)

Comment: @RickJames Nope that also didn't worked.

Comment: I did not expect it to answer your problem; the blog is focused on a small inefficiency in disk usage.

Comment: Can you include the mysql error log contents? It will show why innodb failed to initialize. Which exact MariaDB version?.

Comment: @danblack Sure, I'll.

Answer (score 0):

`max_allowed_packet` is limited to 1G, not 26843545600.

`join_buffer_size` should not be more than 1% of RAM.

How much RAM do you have?

Comment: I have 8G RAM, 2 CPU & SSD storage on the server.